# Extract values of innerHTML using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

FF doesn't support InnerText Property. So if i use innerHTML i get `"<NOBR>0057</NOBR>"`. I want to extract 0057 value. How can i get value of innerHTML without html tags using JQuery

Comment: Are you sure asp.net has something to do with your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `text()` method: http://api.jquery.com/text/